# How can I iterate through a map variable in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-route53

Im trying to iterate through a variable type map and i'm not sure how to

This is what i have so far

In my main.tf:

```
resource "aws_route_53_record" "proxy_dns" {
  count = "${length(var.account_name)}"
  zone_id = "${infrastructure.zone_id}"
  name = "proxy-${element(split(",", var.account_name), count.index)}-dns
  type = CNAME
  ttl = 60
  records = ["{records.dns_name}"]
}
```

And in my variables.tf

```
variable "account_name" {
  type = "map"
  default = {
    "account1" = "accountA"
    "account2" = "accountB"
  }
}
```

I want to be able to create multiple resources with the different account names

Answer (score 48, accepted):

If you are using Terraform 0.12.6 or later then you can use [`for_each`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#for_each-multiple-resource-instances-defined-by-a-map-or-set-of-strings) instead of `count` to produce one instance for each element in your map:

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "proxy_dns" {
  for_each = var.account_name

  zone_id = infrastructure.zone_id
  name    = "proxy-${each.value}-dns"
  # ... etc ...
}
```

The primary advantage of `for_each` over `count` is that Terraform will identify the instances by the key in the map, so you'll get instances like `aws_route53_record.proxy_dns["account1"]` instead of `aws_route53_record.proxy_dns[0]`, and so you can add and remove elements from your map in future with Terraform knowing which specific instance belongs to each element.

`each.key` and `each.value` in the resource type arguments replace `count.index` when `for_each` is used. They evaluate to the key and value of the current map element, respectively.

Comment: Could I exclude an element using for_each?

Comment: You can't do that using `for_each` itself, but you _can_ produce a new map with some of the items filtered out using a [`for` expression](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#for-expressions). That's a different question than I was answering here so I can't go into details in a comment here but if you give that a try and have further questions I'd suggest starting a new question here in Stack Overflow to discuss it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of map, keys function,index function, and count. This terraform creates 3 acls with various rules.

- The names of the acl's are determined by the keys.
- The number of acl's is determined by the count of the keys.
- The index of each rule (priority) is determined by the index function
- The name of each rule is from the CONTAINS_WORD or CONTAINS property in the map

=>

```
variable "acls" {
  type = map(any)
  default = {

    "acl1" = {
      "CONTAINS_WORD" = ["api","aaa", "bbb", "ccc"]
      "CONTAINS" = ["xxx","yyy"]
    }

    "acl2" = {
      "CONTAINS_WORD" = [ "url1,"url2","url3"]
      "CONTAINS" = ["url4"]
    }

    "acl3" = {
      "CONTAINS_WORD" = ["xxx"]
      "CONTAINS" = []
    } 
  }
}

resource "aws_wafv2_web_acl" "acl" {
  name  = keys(var.acls)[count.index]
  scope = "REGIONAL"
  count = length(keys(var.acls))

  default_action {
    block {}
  }

  dynamic "rule" {

    for_each = toset(var.acls[keys(var.acls)[count.index]].CONTAINS_WORD)

    content {
      name     =  rule.key
      priority = index(var.acls[keys(var.acls)[count.index]].CONTAINS_WORD, rule.key)

      action {
        allow {}
      }

      statement {
        
        #https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/APIReference/API_ByteMatchStatement.html
        byte_match_statement  {

          positional_constraint = "CONTAINS_WORD"
          search_string         = lower(rule.key)

          field_to_match {
            uri_path {}
          }

          text_transformation {
            priority = 0
            type     = "LOWERCASE"
          }
        }
      } 

      visibility_config {
        cloudwatch_metrics_enabled = true
        metric_name                = "waf-${keys(var.acls)[count.index]}-${rule.key}"
        sampled_requests_enabled   = true
      }
    }
  }

  dynamic "rule" {

    for_each = toset(var.acls[keys(var.acls)[count.index]].CONTAINS)

    content {
      name     = replace(rule.key, ".", "_")
      priority = index(var.acls[keys(var.acls)[count.index]].CONTAINS, rule.key) + length(var.acls[keys(var.acls)[count.index]].CONTAINS_WORD)

      action {
        allow {}
      }

      statement {
        
        #https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/APIReference/API_ByteMatchStatement.html
        byte_match_statement  {

          positional_constraint = "CONTAINS"
          search_string         = lower(rule.key)

          field_to_match {
            uri_path {}
          }

          text_transformation {
            priority = 0
            type     = "LOWERCASE"
          }
        }
      } 

      visibility_config {
        cloudwatch_metrics_enabled = true
        metric_name                = "waf-${keys(var.acls)[count.index]}-${replace(rule.key, ".", "_")}"
        sampled_requests_enabled   = true
      }
    }
  }


  visibility_config {
    cloudwatch_metrics_enabled = true
    metric_name                = "waf-${keys(var.acls)[count.index]}"
    sampled_requests_enabled   = true
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Make the variable a list instead of a map. Maps are used to reference a name to a value. Lists are better for iterating over via a count method.

```
variable "account_name" {
  type = "list"
  default = {"accountA","accountB"}
}
```

```
resource "aws_route_53_record" "proxy_dns" {
    count = "${length(var.account_name)}"
    zone_id = "${infrastructure.zone_id}"
    name = "proxy-${element(var.account_name, count.index)}-dns
    type = CNAME
    ttl = 60
    records = ["{records.dns_name}"]
}
```