# how can I pull data from this structure in terraform?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have this structure in a terraform output:

```
"eks_private_subnets_in_zones": {
  "value": {
    "us-east-1a": [
      "subnet-11111111111111111",
      "subnet-22222222222222222"
    ],
    "us-east-1b": [
      "subnet-33333333333333333",
      "subnet-44444444444444444"
    ],
    "us-east-1c": [
      "subnet-55555555555555555",
      "subnet-66666666666666666"
    ]
  },
```

How can I produce a list of subnets, which are one of the subnets (say, the first one) from each AZ? To be clear, I want:

```
["subnet-111111111111111111", "subnet-33333333333333333", "subnet-55555555555555555"]
```

I tried

```
{for az in eks_private_subnets_in_zones: subnet.id => az[0]}
```

But I'm completely lost here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the [values function](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/values):

```
output "first_subnet_in_each_availability_zone" {
  value = [for subnet_list in values(eks_private_subnets_in_zones.value) : subnet_list[0]]
}
```

This code snippet does the following:

- It iterates over the values of the eks_private_subnets_in_zones.value map, which are lists of subnet IDs.
- For each list `subnet_list` it takes the first element `subnet_list[0]`, which corresponds to the first subnet in each availability zone.
- It constructs a new list of these first subnet IDs and assigns it to
  the output named first_subnet_in_each_availability_zone.

After applying this configuration with terraform apply, the output
first_subnet_in_each_availability_zone will contain the list of the
first subnet from each availability zone as requested:

```
["subnet-11111111111111111", "subnet-33333333333333333", "subnet-55555555555555555"]
```

The for expression is documented in detail in the [Terraform language documentation](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/for). Additionally, This is [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57503110/how-can-i-iterate-through-a-map-variable-in-terraform) of using for expressions to manipulate collections. For further insights into loops and other control structures in Terraform you might find the article [Terraform tips & tricks: loops, if-statements, and gotchas](https://blog.gruntwork.io/terraform-tips-tricks-loops-if-statements-and-gotchas-f739bbae55f9) by Yevgeniy Brikman helpful.

Comment: I am not sure I did what you recommended: in the project that is consuming the data structure above, I created a local: 
    first_eks_private_subnet_in_each_zone = [for az_subnets in values(data.terraform_remote_state.network.outputs.eks_private_subnets_in_zones.value) : az_subnets[0]]

Comment: Yeah seems like you are using the  same approach to iterate over the values of eks_private_subnets_in_zones.value and create a new list (first_eks_private_subnet_in_each_zone) containing the first subnet ID from each availability zone.

This code is consistent with the explanation provided earlier, and it should work as intended to generate a list of the first subnet from each availability zone.

if it is working as expected, perhaps you can upvote the answer so that someone else in the future can use it as a reference